# Look for the resource to match a key word

Tags: terraform

Suppose I have two kineses, I'd like to get the one of them with the key word `_consumer`.

```
variable "kinesis" {
  default = ["kinesis_publisher", "kinesis_consumer"]
}

resource "aws_kinesis_stream" "test_stream" {
  count = "${length(var.kinesis)}"
  name             = "${var.kinesis[count.index]}"
  shard_count      = 1
  retention_period = 48

  shard_level_metrics = [
    "IncomingBytes",
    "OutgoingBytes",
  ]

  tags = {
    Environment = "test"
  }
}
```

How do I get consumer arn only?

```
output "kinesis_consumer_arn" {
  value = "??? lookup or matchkeys with _consumer ???"
}
```

It is not always the same sequence and will be many kinesis. So I can't use 0 or 1 directly.

Answer (score 0):

You may create modules for each kafka stream , thereby giving more control on variables passed into and derived from the resources.

```
module "kinesis_publisher" {

    source          = "../modules/test_stream"
    stream_name     = "kinesis_publisher"
    }

module "kinesis_consumer" {

    source          = "../modules/test_stream"
    stream_name     = "kinesis_consumer"
    }
```

And then output can be filtered on basis of modules.

```
output "kinesis_consumer_arn" {
  value = "{module.kinesis_consumer.arn}"
}
```